# biblatex: move backrefpages to after the period

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, back-referencing

I've used some tips about how to toy with the format of backrefs in biblatex, and I'm seeing that the formatting is quite flexible.  In the screenshot below, I've put the backref into a box.  That's fun, but I'd like the backref to appear *after* the period, i.e., after the entire citation, like this:

1. M. Nowak, *Science* **314**, 1560-1563 (2006). <kbd>See p. 1</kbd>

*Not* like this:

[image: Box is before the period...]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[natbib=true,
            hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            style=science,
            sorting=nyt,
            autocite=superscript,
            isbn=false,
            backref=true,
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=100,
            block=none]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    backrefpage  = {See p.}, % for single page number
    backrefpages = {See pp.} % for multiple page numbers
}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
  \fbox{
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
     {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}
  }}}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{nowak2006five,
  title={Five rules for the evolution of cooperation},
  author={Nowak, M.A.},
  journal={Science},
  volume={314},
  number={5805},
  pages={1560--1563},
  year={2006},
  publisher={American Association for the Advancement of Science}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{references.bib}

\begin{document}
Evolutionary games.\supercite{nowak2006five}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Update**
I've tried the fix from Guido in the accepted answer below -- it works with my MWE, but introduces another problem when there is more than one bibliography entry (see [MNWE](http://pastebin.com/kjrMb5zj)).  I expect it just needs minor changes...

[image: No period, but an extra comma]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDITED ANSWER AFTER COMMENTS**

The period at the end of a reference is inserted by the bibmacro `finentry`, which is the last instruction of standard biblatex entry drivers. One of the thing `finenty` does is to print the final period using `\finentrypunct`.

Thus to avoid to print the period at the end one has to redefine it:

```
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\iflistundef{pageref}{}{\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}}\finentry}
```

With this definition, it redefines `\finentrypoint` to be empty if there is back reference (`pageref`).

The next step is to print a period before the back reference. To this end the definition of the `pageref` bibmacro has to include such an instruction, `\setunit{\adddot\addspace}`, at the  beginning of false clause of the `\iflistundef{pageref}`.

```
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\setunit{\adddot\addspace}\printtext{%
  \fbox{
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
     {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}
  }}}}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that solves the problem when there's one bibitem, but with more, it introduces another problem.  I've posted a screenshot and MNWE in the question above, further help would be awesome! -J

Comment: `\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}` seems to do a better job of avoiding the period at the end without causing any chaos, see http://www.khirevich.com/latex/biblatex/

Comment: @JoeCorneli Redefining `\finentrypunct` is indeed the way to go; `\finentry` does more than just print `\finentrypunct` and it should be executed at the end of every bibliography entry.

Comment: Just redefining `\finetrypunct` leave entries without `pageref` with no final period.