# How add biblatex backref after period at end of each item in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

The source below, along with the `biblatex.cfg` shown, produces this bibliography that includes backrefs:

[image: actual]

Even without any backrefs, each item in the printed bibliography ends with a period.

How can do the following...

- move the final period so as to go *before* the backref?
- insert a period after each backref's closing parenthesis?
- change each backref's parentheses to square brackets?

... so that the bibliography will look like this:

[image: desired bibliography backrefs]

The source:

```
% File backref.tex
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@article{article,
    author = {Author, An},
    title = {An article},
    journal = {Articles},
    volume = {1}, pages = {1--2}, year = {2021},
}
@book{book,
    author = {Writer, Some},
    title = {A Book},
    publisher = {Publisher}, address = {London},
    year = {2021},
}
\end{filecontents}
  
\begin{filecontents}{backref.lbx}
  \ProvidesFile{backref.lbx}
  % Added after original MWE post...
  % ... included in actual book-length doc:
  \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
  \DeclareBibliographyExtras{%
    \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{%
  \begingroup%
   \@tempcnta0#1\relax\number\@tempcnta%%
      \endgroup}%
  \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
  }
  \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    inherit = {english},
    urlseen = {{accessed}{accessed}},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[citestyle=numeric,backref=true]{biblatex} 
\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  backrefpage = {Cited on page},
  backrefpages = {Cited on pages},
}
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\begin{document}

  In \textcite{article} and \textcite{book}\dots

  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The biblatex config file [**corrected**]:

```
% BIBLATEX.CFG - mimic amsplain
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

% Punctuation & delimiter mods:
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{backref} % external file!
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

% Field mods:
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article]
  {title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}% no quote marks
  \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article]
  {volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}  
%  
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field

% Book mods:
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

% Article mods: 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% number of a journal

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}
  \newunit}
```

Comment: Those things might just be the remnants of more complex code in a slightly bigger document, but in this example the `.lbx` file does nothing (and I would recommend you choose a name that also reflects the language - `english` - it is based on), because it is not selected anywhere, much less so because you actually redefine the language strings with the preamble commands. ...

Comment: ... In a document preamble it is *extremely* unusual (and generally not recommended) to load styles with `\RequireBibliographyStyle`. In this specific setup these lines won't do any harm, but the 'correct' way to load a numeric bib style, is to drop the `\RequireBibliographyStyle` lines and replace `citestyle=numeric,` with `style=numeric,` (which will set both `bibstyle` and `citestyle` to `numeric`). Of course if this is part of a custom `.bbx` file, things are different.

Comment: With that `biblatex.cfg` `backref.lbx` is used after all. But in its current form it is basically useless and crucially it does not contain the actual string redefinitions you apply to `backrefpage` and `backrefpages`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The punctuation directly before the backref is controlled by `\bibpagerefpunct`, which we can redefine to print the `\finentrypunct` (plus a space). Then we just need to make sure that after the backref is printed, no further `\finentrypunct` is inserted, so we reset its definition in the `pageref` bibmacro. We also change the brackets via the field format used in `pageref`. (The original definition of that macro can be found in [`biblatex.def`, ll. 2934-2941 in v3.16](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2934-L2941).)

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[style=numeric,backref=true]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  backrefpage  = {cited on page},
  backrefpages = {cited on pages},
}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagerefpunct}{%
  \finentrypunct\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bracketswithperiod}{\mkbibbrackets{#1\addperiod}}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[bracketswithperiod]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}%
     \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  In \textcite{sigfridsson} and \textcite{worman}\dots

  \clearpage

  In \textcite{sigfridsson} and \textcite{nussbaum}\dots

  \clearpage

  In \textcite{sigfridsson} and \textcite{geer,nussbaum}\dots

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. [Cited on pages 1–3.]]

Comment: With the bibliography format used in my MWE -- modified numeric and the indicated biblatex.cfg (see my corrected post) --  this proposed solution fails to insert a period at the end of the entry (before the backref addition).

Comment: @murray Neither adding the code from your `biblatex` config file to my MWE directly nor externalising it to `biblatex.cfg` stopped the period from showing up before the backref. There must be some other code (that you haven't shown) that stops it from doing that.

Comment: Looking at the `biblatex.cfg` I see no code that looks as though it should stop my code from working. The only unknown is `backref.lbx`, if your actual file contains more than the stub shown in the question.

Comment: Please see my updated post which now includes the entirety of my actual `backref.lbx`. (Sorry for trying to strip things down to what I thought were the only essentials to concoct the MWE.)

Comment: @murray Mhh, that's not it, either. I still get the period before the backref even with the new `.lbx` file. Can you please check that my MWE exactly as posted works for you. Can you then check if it works together with your `biblatex.cfg`. When exactly do things fall apart?

Comment: Aha: I had put your new bib commands into the .lbx, which failed to put the period at the end of the part of the entry preceding the "[Cited...]" bacref stuff. However, when I moved those commands into my .tex source file, the period appeared where wanted. I don't understand why it makes a difference as to where the definitions are placed; must have something to do with when the .lbx is read and used?

Comment: @murray The `.lbx` file is only read when the language is selected and it is read in a group, which means that basically all the definitions that are integral to this answer (which are local) are simply discarded. The `.lbx` should really only contain `\DeclareBibliographyExtras` and `\DeclareBibliographyStrings` (or the respective inheritance declarations): Style modifications should not be contained in the `.lbx` file, they belong into the preamble, a `.bbx`/`.cbx` file or `biblatex.cfg`.

Answer (score 4):

My attempt below was inspired by [biblatex: move backrefpages to after the period](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113264/biblatex-move-backrefpages-to-after-the-period).

[image]

```
% File backref.tex
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@article{article,
    author = {Author, An},
    title = {An article},
    journal = {Articles},
    volume = {1}, pages = {1--2}, year = {2021},
}
@book{book,
    author = {Writer, Some},
    title = {A Book},
    publisher = {Publisher}, address = {London},
    year = {2021},
}
\end{filecontents}
  
\begin{filecontents}{backref.lbx}
  \ProvidesFile{backref.lbx}
  \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[citestyle=numeric,backref=true]{biblatex} 
\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  backrefpage = {Cited on page},
  backrefpages = {Cited on pages},
}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\iflistundef{pageref}{}{\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}}\finentry}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\setunit{\adddot\addspace}\printtext{%
        \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
                     {[\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
                       {[\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
                         \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}\adddot]}}}

\addbibresource{testbib.bib}
\begin{document}

In \textcite{article}% and \textcite{book}\dots
\newpage
In \textcite{article}  and \textcite{book}\dots

  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does not work if an item is cited on more than one page. E.g., if I append to the document body `\newpage In \textcite{article} also \dots`, then the first bibliography item now ends with: "(2021), 1-2. [Cited on pages.] Cited on page 1, 2."

Comment: @murray, my bad. It's fixed.